# How to call Bootstrap formValidation with Jquery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to call Bootstrap formValidation on a Jquery UI dialog. But its not working. I have try a lot of thods but its not helping.Can someone guide me please.

My Validation which I want to call is

**jQuery Code**

```
    $('#form_question').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        excluded: ':disabled',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                newq_title_error: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The username is required'
                            },
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 4,
                            message: 'The username must be more than 4'
                            }
                        }
                }                                                
        }
    });
```

**My jquery UI dialog form is**

```
<div class='new_question ui-front' id='new_question'>
<form id='form_question' name='form_question' action=''>
<span class='iconclose'><i class='fa fa-close fa-lg'></i></span>
<div id='error_title' class='error error-bk' style='display:none;' align='center'>Please check the following errors</div>
<div id='general_error' class='error error-bk' style='display:none;' align='center'></div>

  <p class='newq_subtitle'>Title*</p>
     <div class='newq_text_div'>
        <div class='newq_text' id='newq_text'>               
            <input type='text' class='newq_title' id='newq_title' name='newq_title' autocomplete='off'  >
            <span id='newq_title_error' class='error'   style='display:none;'></span>
        </div>
    </div>    
 </form>         
</div>
```

**This is popup comes when we click a Button**

```
    <button class='btn btn-primary' type='button' id='asknew'>Ask Question</button>
```

**Jquery for this is**

```
askquestion_dialog(function(event, ui) {    
            var questionbox=$("#new_question"); 
            $('button#postnew').unbind('click').click(function(event, ui) {
                #Old validation code was here. I have tested putting formvalidation here. But didnt work here too       
            });
        }).dialog('open');
```

**Askquestion dialog function**

```
function askquestion_dialog(fnopen)
    {

    return $("#new_question").dialog({
             dialogClass: 'new_question',
             position: ['center', 70],
             autoOpen:false,
             modal:true,
             width:710,
             height:640,
             resizable:false,
             open: fnopen,
             close: function(event) {   
                 /*if(!$(event.currentTarget).hasClass('ui-dialog-titlebar-close')) {
                        load_question(questionid);
                 }*/
                $(this).find("#form_question").trigger('reset');
                $(this).find("#tags_choose").trigger("chosen:updated");
                $(this).dialog('destroy');
            }
        });
    }
```

*Any Idea how to call Bootstrap formValidation on a Jquery UI dialog.Please Help*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later, I found the solution. As the bootstrap validation and Jquery UI conflicting, I have call manually the validation on Onblur of each form element

```
function validateQuestionTitle(){
     var title = $("#newq_title").val();
      if(title == ''){
        $('#newq_title').css('border-color', 'red'); 
        $('#newq_success').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok newq_title-feedback').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove newq_title-feedback'); 
        $("#newq_title_error").html("Please provide a Title").show();
      }else{
        $('#newq_title').css('border-color', 'green'); 
        $('#newq_success').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove newq_title-feedback').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok newq_title-feedback');    
        $("#newq_title_error").html("").hide();
      }  
}
```